# How to slice string after dot in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php
function string_excerpt($string, $count){
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    if (count($words) > $count)
    {
        $words = array_slice($words, 0, $count);
        $string = implode(' ', $words);
    }
    return $string;
}

$string = "Some texts";

//The amount of words we want to show
$count = 18;

echo string_excerpt($string, $count);?>
```

This is the code of slice text after count.

Well, this function working good and cut text after count.  But this system cut string after any marks like cut after "," or "just any word". It must be cut after "dot".

Like that: Lorem ipsum doler sit amet. Sit done, asd.
after count and check mark: Lorem ipsum doler sit amet.

Whatever in string, it must be cut string after count and it have to check 'dot' because it have to cut after count and 'dot'.

So what should I do?

Comment: what if the input is `"Lorem ipsum doler sit amet. Sit done, asd. after count "` and the count is `9`? what should be the result?

Comment: for example after counting 10 words, it have to check dot mark in these inside of 10 words and if it find dot. so it must be cut after dot.

Comment: You might be better of using '.' with `explode`. Check the number of words in each array element add them to a dummy array while keeping track of total count. If total number gets higher than '$count` then stop adding text, put the string back together using the dummy array and add a '.', then return the string.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to split the string after the amount of words. Then, if there is a dot inside, you want to split it again on the dot? Say you split after 10 words. What will happen if there are 30 words? Will it split on into 3 strings of 10 words, or 2 strings of 10 words and 20 words? You realy have to clerify your question on this.

Comment: So if I say $count = 100; it have to count find dot in 100 words. You are right maybe it cant find any dot in 100 words. So in this case it have to over count and find dot near the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
       <?php
    function string_excerpt($string, $count){

    $words_counter = str_word_count($string);

        if ($words_counter > $count)
        {
$ans = get_words($string, $count);
           $string = str_replace($ans,"",$string);
        $sentences  = explode(".",$string);
        foreach($sentences as $sentence){
        if(str_word_count($ans)>=$count && substr(trim($ans),-1,1)=="."){
        return $ans;
        }
        $ans .= $sentence.".";

        }

        }
        return $string;
    }
    $string = "Lorem ipsum doler sit amet. Sit done, asd.";

    //The amount of words we want to show
    $count = 6;
function get_words($string, $count = 18) {
    preg_match("/(?:\w+(?:\W+|$)){0,$count}/", $string, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

    echo string_excerpt($string, $count);

    ?>
```

Comment: Your solution is cutting html tags . so my HTML page is crying with this solution.

Comment: OK, you didn't say something about html. if you want i will try to get better solution and improve the answer.

Comment: Add a sample include HTML and i will improve it.

Comment: Ok Im trying your solution

Comment: I change it, try now.

Comment: Now it breaking html tags. Maybe you have to see my project and I can tell you really what i want. So I have to contact with you. if you want. You can mail me.

Comment: That way we can find solution together.

Comment: No problem, what is your email ?

Answer (score -1):

So if i understand it right. 
You have some string. After "length" number of words, you want to find next after "length" numer "dot" and cut string there?
I would do it like this:

```
function string_excerpt($string, $count){
    $tmpString = explode(' ',$string);
    $returnWord = '';
    $id = 0;
    foreach($tmpString as $word){
        if($id <= $count) {
            $returnWord .= $word.' ';
            $id++;
        }
    }
    if(strpos($word,'.')===false){// no dot in last word.
        for($i=$id; $i<=count($tmpString);$i++){// till we not found dot, add next word
            $returnWord .= $tmpString[$i].' ';
            if(strpos($tmpString[$i],'.')!==false){//dot found...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $returnWord;
}
```

Comment: it works fine but I find some errors. If I change count value to 100 it says: Undefined offset: 140 in $returnWord .= $tmpString[$i].' ';
            if(strpos($tmpString[$i],'.')!==false){//dot found...
                break;

Comment: Possible in line:
for($i=$id; $i<=count($tmpString);$i++){
Should be
for($i=$id; $i<count($tmpString);$i++){
So without "=" in $i<count...

or add if(isset($tmpString[$i])){ 
on beginning of for (but after it start)

Comment: Its not the correct answer.. Ex. 10 spaces between two words will return wrong answer.

Comment: Yeah right. minutes ago.I realized when I add more words